# How to convert this linq query to lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this Query :

```
return (from r in this.Requests where r.Status == "Authorised" from i in r.Items select i).Sum(i => i.Value);
```

I tried converting it to lambda as I prefer that now, so I did :

`var sum = Requests.Where(x=>x.Status == "Authorised").Select(x=>x.Items).Sum(x=>x.Value);` --> and here I got no `Value` Item, any ideas why?

Comment: Can't see the last part of your converted code - can you update your question?

Comment: Might be because you are using var, it can screw with the intellisense.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid: `var` absolutely should *not* mess with Intellisense, as it's all still statically typed.

Comment: @JonSkeet nevertheless it does on occasion.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid: You'll need to give a concrete example for that to be useful, really...

Comment: @JonSkeet I was thinking about that, and it was a colleague who made me aware of it. for example when using a foreach with var instead of DynamicNode (part of Umbraco) you cannot access the variable's attributes, it has to be an explicit DynamicNode.

Comment: @JonSkeet I can also say I have witnessed this, when using RepeaterItem inside a foreach look in webforms. If I use (var ri in Repeater.Items){ //ri not recognised as repeaterItem in VS2010SP1 here}

Comment: @MuhammadA: That's because `ri` is statically typed as `object`, because `RepeaterItemCollection` just implements `IEnumerable`. You'd get exactly the same behaviour if you explicitly typed it as `object`. That's not an intellisense issue at all - it's the way the language infers the type.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid: That's almost certainly the same problem as MuhammadA referred to. The explicit typing there adds a cast; the `var` infers the type as `object`. Again, this is *not* an Intellisense issue at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, mate, always good to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `SelectMany` instead of `Select`. Your query is basically equivalent to:

```
return this.Requests
           .Where(r => r.Status == "Authorised")
           .SelectMany(r => r.Items)
           .Sum(i => i.Value);
```

Note that your original query would have been clearer on multiple lines too...